# how to remove quote gracefully from calcite parser?

Tags: apache-calcite

I have a table and I am trying to parse it's create statement like
[image]

As we seen, all fields of this sqlNode are quoted by ` . But this is not what I want

How to remove all the quotes by SqlWriterConfig? thanks

Answer (score 0):

In SqlWriterConfig, there is:

```java
/** Sets {@link #quoteAllIdentifiers}. */
SqlWriterConfig withQuoteAllIdentifiers(boolean quoteAllIdentifiers);
```

you can pass argument as `false`.